# Distinguishing between when a script is ran 'directly', or with Python executable

Tags: python, boolean, executable, execution, self

How can a Python program determine if it was executed as an executable file on a Unix system instead of being called as a script?

```
./program.py
```

instead of

```
python ./program.py
```

'/program' in `sys.argv[0]` cannot distinguish between the example cases.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Unix doesn't make a distinction between the cases, the shell will just execute `python program.py` for you when it encounters a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line.

Comment: What type of problem would this knowledge solve? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat hackish solution would be adding an environment variable indicating this to the shebang line in `program.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env noscript=True python
import os
if os.getenv('noscript'):
    print("called as executable")
else: 
    print("called as script")
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is no distinction. If you set the executable bit, the os ultimately does exactly what you do on the command line -- it does `python script.py`. The only difference is that the os looks at the first line beginning with `#!` to determine precisely what version of python to run.